# Invalid use of non-static data member for accesing array in a struct

Tags: c++

I am trying to work with JUCE Demo, and extract portions of [BinaryData.cpp](https://github.com/julianstorer/JUCE/blob/master/examples/Demo/JuceLibraryCode/BinaryData.cpp) and [OpenGLDemo.cpp](https://github.com/julianstorer/JUCE/blob/master/examples/Demo/Source/Demos/OpenGLDemo.cpp) into my own class. Unfortunately, I run into a problem I can't really parse, which I've managed to reduce in this minimal example of three files: `main.cpp`, `mystuff.cpp` and `mystuff.h`:

`main.cpp`:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp mystuff.cpp -o main

#include "mystuff.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  MyStuff tmpstuff;
  std::cout << "hello world" << tmpstuff.temp_binary_data_7[0] << std::endl ;
}
```

`mystuff.h`

```
#include <iostream>

class MyStuff
{
public:
  MyStuff();
  ~MyStuff();

  // from BinaryData.cpp:
  //~ static const unsigned char temp_binary_data_7[] =
  //~ { 35,32,77,97,120,50,79,98,106,32,86,101,114,115,105,111,110,32,52,46,48,32,77,97,114,32,49,48,116,104,44,32,50,48,48,49,10,35,10,35,32,111,98,106,101,99,116,32,84,101,97,112,111,116,48,49,32,116,111,32,99,111,109,101,32,46,46,46,10,35,10,118,32,32,53,
  //~ 46,57,50,57,54,56,56,32,52,46,49,50,53,48,48,48,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,48,48,10,118,32,32,53,46,56,51,50,48,51,49,32,52,46,52,57,52,49,52,49,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,48,48,10,118,32,32,53,46,57,52,53,51,49,51,32,52,46,54,49,55,49,56,56,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,
  //~ 48,48,10,118,32,32,54,46,49,55,53,55,56,49,32,52,46,52,57,52,49,52,49,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,48,48,10,118,32,32,54,46,52,50,57,54,56,56,32,52,46,49,50,53,48,48,48,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,48,48,10,118,32,32,53,46,51,56,55,49,56,56,32,52,46,49,50,53,48,48,48
  //~ };
  // move definition to .cpp because of 'error: in-class initialization of static data member ‘const unsigned char MyStuff::temp_binary_data_7 []’ of incomplete type'
  static const unsigned char temp_binary_data_7[];

  const char* teapot_obj = (const char*) temp_binary_data_7;

  // from OpenGLDemo.cpp:
  struct Shape
  {
    Shape()
    {
      std::cout << "initializing " << static_cast<void*>(teapot_obj) << std::endl ;
    }
  };
};
```

`mystuff.cpp`:

```
#include "mystuff.h"

const unsigned char MyStuff::temp_binary_data_7[] =
{ 35,32,77,97,120,50,79,98,106,32,86,101,114,115,105,111,110,32,52,46,48,32,77,97,114,32,49,48,116,104,44,32,50,48,48,49,10,35,10,35,32,111,98,106,101,99,116,32,84,101,97,112,111,116,48,49,32,116,111,32,99,111,109,101,32,46,46,46,10,35,10,118,32,32,53,
46,57,50,57,54,56,56,32,52,46,49,50,53,48,48,48,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,48,48,10,118,32,32,53,46,56,51,50,48,51,49,32,52,46,52,57,52,49,52,49,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,48,48,10,118,32,32,53,46,57,52,53,51,49,51,32,52,46,54,49,55,49,56,56,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,
48,48,10,118,32,32,54,46,49,55,53,55,56,49,32,52,46,52,57,52,49,52,49,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,48,48,10,118,32,32,54,46,52,50,57,54,56,56,32,52,46,49,50,53,48,48,48,32,48,46,48,48,48,48,48,48,10,118,32,32,53,46,51,56,55,49,56,56,32,52,46,49,50,53,48,48,48
};

MyStuff::MyStuff() {

}
MyStuff::~MyStuff() {

}
```

When I compile with `g++`, I get this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp mystuff.cpp -o main
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
mystuff.h: In constructor ‘MyStuff::Shape::Shape()’:
mystuff.h:18:42: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘MyStuff::teapot_obj’
   const char* teapot_obj = (const char*) temp_binary_data_7;
                                          ^
mystuff.h:25:58: error: from this location
       std::cout << "initializing " << static_cast<void*>(teapot_obj) << std::endl ;
                                                          ^
In file included from mystuff.cpp:1:0:
mystuff.h: In constructor ‘MyStuff::Shape::Shape()’:
mystuff.h:18:42: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘MyStuff::teapot_obj’
   const char* teapot_obj = (const char*) temp_binary_data_7;
                                          ^
mystuff.h:25:58: error: from this location
       std::cout << "initializing " << static_cast<void*>(teapot_obj) << std::endl ;
                                                          ^
```

This happens only when the `struct Shape` code exists in `mystuff.h` - if you delete it, then the code compiles and runs fine.

So what are my options? How can I define the `struct Shape` (or the other variables) so that it can refer to `teapot_obj` without compilation errors?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to fix it by just throwing expressions here and there, but it would still be great to read an answer that explains what is actually going on... here are my changes - only in `mystuff.h`:

`mystuff.h`:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyStuff
{
public:
  MyStuff();
  ~MyStuff();

  static const unsigned char temp_binary_data_7[];
  static constexpr const char* teapot_obj = (const char*) temp_binary_data_7;

  // from OpenGLDemo.cpp:
  struct Shape
  {
    Shape()
    {
      std::cout << "initializing " << static_cast<const void*>(teapot_obj) << std::endl ;
    }
  };
  Shape tmptest;
};
```

So, basically:

```
const char* teapot_obj = (const char*) temp_binary_data_7;
```

had to change into:

```
static constexpr const char* teapot_obj = (const char*) temp_binary_data_7;
```

... which then means I have to make a `static_cast<const void*>` (instead of just `static_cast<void*>`) to print out the object address; and finally, have to add a `Shape tmptest;` so that the constructor of `Shape` runs at least once, so we can have something printed.

And now, the program runs without problems:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp mystuff.cpp -o main
$ ./main 
initializing 0x400c60
hello world#
```